# pass a void in paramettre onclick in a loop for

Tags: java, android, json, onclick

I create my views dynamically and the buttons,
I want to pass a string parameter in the onclick void that is in my loop, but always take the last value linkbutton node !!

```
if (type.equals("link") == true )
{
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     if (classe.equals("text") ==  true)
     {
         Button txtlink= new Button(getApplicationContext());
         txtlink.setText(value); 
         txtlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {

                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    buttonClick(linkButton);
                }
         });
         ll.addView(txtlink);
     }
    else if(classe.equals("button") ==  true)
     {    

         Button btn_entregistrer = new Button(getApplicationContext());
         btn_entregistrer.setText(value);
         ll.addView(btn_entregistrer);

         btn_entregistrer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        buttonClick(linkButton);
            }
         });          
     }   
}
```

what to do?

Comment: I don't see any loop...

Answer (score 2):

> It will always take last value because you did not define and initialize  **linkButton** variable inside the loop.

Before passing the value in click , Declare and initialization of variable compulsaory.

**Inside the loop**

```
String linkButton="value";
 if (type.equals("link") == true )
{
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


if (classe.equals("text") ==  true)
 {
     Button txtlink= new Button(getApplicationContext());
     txtlink.setText(value); 
     txtlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                buttonClick(linkButton);
            }
     });
     ll.addView(txtlink);
 }
else if(classe.equals("button") ==  true)
 {    

     Button btn_entregistrer = new Button(getApplicationContext());
     btn_entregistrer.setText(value);
     ll.addView(btn_entregistrer);

     btn_entregistrer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    buttonClick(linkButton);
        }
     });          
 } }
```

Comment: this is solution i change my variable linkbutton to final string inside loop for , before i declared my variable outside loop for

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are not changing the value for linkButton. That's the reason why always gets the same value.